# How to render a localized date interval in Swift

Tags: swift, date, localization, intervals

I need to render an interval between two dates that can be properly localized, as following:

- in British English: `13 - 16 Apr`
- in American English: `Apr 13 - 16`
- in French: `13-16 avr.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`NSDateIntervalFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDateIntervalFormatter_class/) class.

Swift Playground example:

```
import Foundation

let dateIntervalFormatter = DateIntervalFormatter()

let fromDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -123456789.0)
let toDate = Date()

dateIntervalFormatter.dateTemplate = "d MMM"
dateIntervalFormatter.string(from: fromDate, to: toDate)
// Outputs "Feb 1, 1997 – Jun 5, 2019"

dateIntervalFormatter.dateTemplate = "EEE, MMM d, ''yy"
dateIntervalFormatter.string(from: fromDate, to: toDate)
// Outputs "Sat, Feb 1, 97 – Wed, Jun 5, 19"

dateIntervalFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
dateIntervalFormatter.string(from: fromDate, to: toDate)
// Outputs "sam. 1 févr. 97 – mer. 5 juin 19"
```

Optionally set the locale if you want to render the date interval in a locale that's different from the current locale by setting `locale` property on the formatter instance.

You can compose your own format in `dateTemplate`, following date format patterns as defined in [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Alternatively, you can use system pre-defined date and time styles by setting `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` properties of the `NSDateIntervalFormatter` instance (See  [NSDateIntervalFormatter Formatter Options](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDateIntervalFormatter_class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSDateIntervalFormatterStyle) for more details of pre-defined formats).

Comment: you've just copied the info from the documentation. In fact, there's no way to customize the dateTemplate. Please let me know if you successfully used smth else than predefined templates

Comment: @CheshireKat I've updated the code to reflect a working example that you can copy/paste in a Swift Playground. It does work the way it's documented if your template string follows a valid pattern defined in the Unicode Tech Standard #35